# How to calculate determinants of such types?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, determinants

Consider next determinant that we want to expand around $h=1$
\begin{eqnarray}
Z_q \ = \ h^{N N_f} \  \ \left ( \prod_{n=1}^{N}  \ \sum_{l_n=0}^{N_f -q} \ h^{2l_n+q}  \ \binom{N_f}{l_n} \right ) \ \underset{1\le i,j\le N}{\det} \binom{N_f}{l_i-i+j+q}  \ . \label{PF_form_343}
\end{eqnarray}

General structure of the expansion near $h=1$
$$
\prod_{n = 1}^N e^{l_n m }  = \prod_{n = 1}^N (1 +   l_n m + \frac{l_n^2}{2!} m^2  + \frac{ l_n^3}{3!} m^3 +...) = 1+  \sum_{n =1}^N l_n m + 
$$
$$
+ \frac{1}{2!} \left (  \sum_{n =1}^N l_n^2 + \sum_{n\neq m =1}^N  l_n l_m  \right) m^2 +  \frac{1}{3!} \left(  \sum_{n =1}^N l_n^3 + 3 \sum_{n\neq m  =1}^N l_n^2 l_m  + \sum_{n\neq m \neq r =1}^N  l_n l_m l_r   \right) m^3 + 
$$
$$
+ \frac{1}{4!}\left (  \sum_{n =1}^N l_n^4 + 4 \sum_{n\neq m  =1}^N l_n^3 l_m + 3  \sum_{n\neq m  =1}^N l_n^2 l_m^2 + 6 \sum_{n\neq m \neq r =1}^N  l_n^2 l_m l_r  + \sum_{n\neq m \neq r \neq s =1}^N  l_n l_m l_r l_s   \right) m^4 +...
$$
We choose $l \to 2 l - N_f -i+j+ q$ to make the most efficient way  of calculation.
$$
Z = e^{(2 l_n - N_f -i+j+ q) \log h} = 1 + (2 l_n - N_f-i+j + q) \log h + \frac{1}{2} (2 l_n - N_f -i+j + q)^2 (\log h)^2 + \frac{1}{6} (2 l_n - N_f -i+j + q)^3 (\log h)^3 
$$
Making summation ( $a=-i+j+q$)
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {n\choose k+a}  = {2n\choose n+a},$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {n\choose k+a} (2 k - n + a) = 0, $$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {n\choose k+a} \frac{(2 k - n + a )^2}{2!}  = -\frac{(a^2-n^2)}{2 (2n-1)} {2n\choose n+a}, $$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {n\choose k+a} \frac{(2 k - n + a )^3}{3!}  = 0 ,
$$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\binom{n}{k+a} \frac{(2 k - n + a )^4}{4!}=
\frac{\left(a^2- n^2\right) \left(4 n +3 \left(a^2- n^2\right) \right)}{4!  (2 n -3) (2 n -1)} \binom{2n}{n+a},
$$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\binom{n}{k+a}\frac{(2 k - n + a )^5}{5!}=
0 
$$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N_f}\binom{N_f}k\binom{N_f}{k+a}\frac{(2 k - N_f + a )^6}{6!}=
- \frac{ (a^2- N_f^2) \left(64 N_f^2- 16 - 60 N_f  (a^2- N_f^2)+15 (a^2- N_f^2)^2\right)}{6! (2 N_f-5) (2 N_f-3) (2 N_f-1)} \binom{2 N_f}{N_f+a}
$$
we come to calculation of the determinants.

I calculated determinants by "brute force" method
(denoting $N_f^2 - (-i+j  + q)^2=t^2$)

1. $$
   \sum_{k=1}^N \det_{1\le i,j\le N} \left[ \frac{t^2}{2(2 N_f - 1)} \delta_{k, i}+ (1-\delta_{k, i}) \right] \binom{2 N_f}{N_f-i+j+q} = \frac{ N (N + 2 N_f) (N_f^2 -q^2) }{2 (4 N_f^2-1)} \, Z_0^{N, N_f} (q) 
   $$
2. $$
    \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \neq  l=1}^N \det_{1\le i,j\le N} \left[ \frac{t^2}{2(2 N_f - 1)} \delta_{k, i}+ (1-\delta_{k, i}) \right]\left[ \frac{t^2}{2(2 N_f - 1)} \delta_{l, i}+ (1-\delta_{l, i}) \right]\times 
   $$
   $$
   \times \binom{2 N_f}{N_f-i+j+ q} =  \frac{(N-1) N (N+2 N_f) (N+2N_f+1) (N_f^2-q^2) ((N_f+1)^2 -q^2)}{16 (N_f+1) (4 N_f^2-1)  (2 N_f+3)} \, Z_0^{N, N_f} (q) \ ,
   $$
3. $$
   \sum_{k=1}^N \det_{1\le i,j\le N} \left[  \frac{ t^2 \left(3 t^2-4 N_f\right)}{4! (2 N_f-3) (2 N_f-1)} \delta_{k, i} + (1-\delta_{k, i}) \right]\binom{2 N_f}{N_f-i+j+q} =
   $$
   $$
   = \left (\frac{ (5 N( N+ 2 N_f)+4 N_f^2+1) (N_f^2-q^2)- (N-1) (N+2  N_f+1)(4 N_f^2+1) }{16(N_f+1) (4 N_f^2- 9)}  - \frac{  N_f}{6( 2 N_f -3)}\right) \frac{N(N+2 N_f) (N_f^2-q^2)}{(4 N_f^2-1) } Z_0^{N, N_f} (q) \ .
   $$
   where
   $$
     Z_0^{N, N_f} (q) =\det_{1\le i, j \le N} \ \binom{2 N_f}{N_f-i +j+q}  =  \frac{ G[N+ 2 N_f+1] G[N+1] G[N_f-q+1] G[N_f+q+1] }{ G[2 N_f+1] G[N+ N_f- q+1] G[N+ N_f+ q+1] }\  \ ,
   $$
   and $G(x)$ is Burness G function.

But the next ones of this type are more sophisticated and require more powerful methods.
For $m^6$ order  I need to calculate at least three determinants

4. $$
   \sum_{k=1}^N \det_{1\le i,j\le N} \left[  \frac{t^2 \left(64 N_f^2- 16 + 60 N_f  t^2+15 t^4\right)}{6! (2 N_f-5) (2 N_f-3) (2 N_f-1)} \delta_{k, i} + (1-\delta_{k, i}) \right]\binom{2 N_f}{N_f-i+j+q}  \ .
   $$
5. $$
   \sum_{k \neq  l=1}^N \det_{1\le i,j\le N} \left[  \frac{t^2 \left(3 t^2 -4 N_f\right)}{4! (2 N_f-3) (2 N_f-1)} \delta_{k, i} + (1-\delta_{k, i}) \right] \left[ \frac{t^2}{2(2 N_f - 1)} \delta_{l, i}+ (1-\delta_{l, i}) \right]\binom{2 N_f}{N_f-i+j+q} 
   $$
6. 

\begin{eqnarray}
 \frac{1}{6} \sum_{k \neq  l \neq r=1}^N \det_{1\le i,j\le N} \left[ \frac{t^2}{2(2 N_f - 1)} \delta_{k, i}+ (1-\delta_{k, i}) \right]\left[ \frac{t^2}{2(2 N_f - 1)} \delta_{l, i}+ (1-\delta_{l, i}) \right] \left[ \frac{t^2}{2(2 N_f - 1)} \delta_{r, i}+ (1-\delta_{r, i}) \right] \binom{2 N_f}{N_f-i+j+q} = (N-2) (N-1) N N_f \times\\ 
\times \frac{  (N+2 N_f)(N+2 N_f+1) (N+2 N_f+2) (N_f^2-q^2) ((N_f+1)^2-q^2) ((N_f+2)^2-q^2)}{96 (N_f+1) (N_f+2) (2 N_f-1) (2 N_f+1)^2 (2 N_f+3) (2 N_f+5)} Z_0^{N, N_f} (q)
\end{eqnarray}

The final result in contrast to separate terms  is very elegant:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{Z_q}{ Z_0^{N, N_f} (q)}= 1 + \frac{m^2 R t}{2 \left(4N_f^2-1\right)} +\frac{m^4 R t}{4! \left(4 N_f^2-1\right) }\left(\frac{3 (R+2) (t-2)}{4 N_f^2-9}-2\right)+  \\
&&  + \frac{m^6 R t }{6! \left(4 N_f^2-1\right)} \left(\frac{20 (R+2) (R+6) (t-2) (t-6)}{\left(4 N_f^2-25\right) \left(4N_f^2-9\right)}+ \frac{10 R (R+2) (t-2) t}{\left(4 N_f^2-9\right) \left(4 N_f^2-1\right)} \right. - \nonumber \\
&&\left. -\frac{15 R (R+6) t (t-6)}{\left(4 N_f^2-25\right) \left(4 N_f^2-1\right)}-\frac{5 (R+6) (t-6)}{4 N_f^2-25} -\frac{45 (R+2) (t-2)}{4 N_f^2-9}+\frac{20 R t}{4 N_f^2-1}+16\right) + O (m^8)
\end{eqnarray}
where
$$
R = N (N + 2N_f ) , \ \ t= N_f^2- q^2
$$

Comment: Where do these determinants come from?  What is your motivation?

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question, and added more information. If you need something else, please ask me.

Comment: There are too many not specified variables from the very beginning, which makes it very difficult to follow the core of your question.

Comment: OK. What is problem in my explanation?

Comment: By the way. I found one of the determinants. The last one.

Comment: Version 17 of this question.

Comment: If you understand this question, why other people are puzzled  with my denotations?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your last equation (6.), there are too many typos ($\delta_{r,i}$ missing, broken frac). Please check carefully and fix. Btw, the rhs of (6.) can be written using Pochhammers $(a)_k$, something like $\frac{N_f^2 (N-2)_3 (N+2 N_f)_3 (N_f-q)_3 (N_f+q)_3}{2 \left(4 N_f^2-1\right) 3! (2 N_f)_{6}} Z_0^{N,N_f}(q)$.

Comment: The typos were caused by incorrect MathJax HTML-CSS rendering. The formulae are simply too long, you should add line breaks. However, I still cannot reproduce (6.), and (2.) neither. (1.) is ok, the others I did not check. The rhs of (2.) can be written similar to my expression above, with 2s instead of 3s.

Comment: Thank you! I check my calculation now. What algorithm do you use?

Comment: OK, I found the error in the OPs post. t should read $N_f^2 - (j-i+q)^2=t^2$ instead of $N_f^2 - (j-i-q)^2=t^2$. Then the checked expressions (1.), (2.) and (6.) seem to be correct. I use Mathematica. The expressions (1.), (2.) and (6.) can be written with Pochhammer symbols, try $\frac{(N-k+1)_k (N+2 N_f)_k (N_f-q)_k (q+N_f)_k}{k! (2 N_f)_{2 k}}$, with $k=\{1,2,3\}$. A trivial factor remains.

Comment: OK. I used your notations. These three dets is most simple things. Unfortunately, the other one is more sophisticated. And the general pattern is not clear.

Comment: Now version 20.

Comment: Fred Hucht You may check now Det 3.

Comment: What exactly looks so funny?

Comment: Now version 25.

Answer (score 0):

Determinant 4 is
$$
\frac{N (N+2 N_f) (N_f^2-q^2) }{96 (N_f+1) (N_f+2) (4 N_f^2- 25) (4 N_f^2-9) (4 N_f^2 -1) } \times 
\left[ N^4 \left(N_f^4+7 \left(5-2 N_f^2\right) q^2-5 N_f^2+21 q^4 +4\right)+4 N^3 N_f \left(N_f^4+7 \left(5-2
   N_f^2\right) q^2-5 N_f^2+21 q^4+4\right)+N^2 \left(7 \left(16 N_f^2+5\right) q^4- N_f (4 N_f (N_f (22 N_f+15)-20)+75) q^2+ N_f (N_f (N_f
   (N_f (4 N_f (2 N_f+3)-11)+3)+13)-15)-5 \left(5 q^2+2\right)\right)+2 N N_f \left(4 N_f^2+5\right) ((N_f+1)^2-q^2)  \left(N_f^2+ N_f-7
   q^2-2\right)+ ((N_f+1)^2-q^2)  \left(N_f \left(2 N_f \left(N_f \left(N_f \left(4 N_f (N_f+4)-4 q^2+19\right)+6\right)-15 q^2+1\right)+7\right)-4q^2+6\right)\right] Z_0^{N,N_f} (q)
$$

Determinant 5 is
$$
\frac{(N-1) N (N+2 N_f) (N+2 N_f+1) (N_f^2-q^2) ((N_f+1)^2-q^2) }{32 (N_f+1) (N_f+2) (4 N_f^2-9) ) (2 N_f+5) \left(1-4 N_f^2\right)^2} \times \left[(N_f+2) \left(N^2 (N_f-1) \left(2 N_f^2+N_f-2\right)+2 N
   (N_f-1) N_f \left(2 N_f^2+N_f-2\right)+(2 N_f-1) \left(2 (N_f+2) (2 N_f+1) N_f^2+3\right)\right)-q^2 \left(N^2+20 N Nf^3+2 (N (5 N+3)+3)   N_f^2+(N (3 N+2)+4) N_f+8 N_f^4-4\right)\right] Z_0^{N,N_f} (q)
$$