# Is it express in terms of Schur Q-function?

Tags: integration, determinants, partitions, schur-functions, pfaffian

Consider next integral
\begin{eqnarray}
Z \ = \ h^{- N N_f} \ \int\limits_{SU(N)} \ dU  \ \prod_{n=1}^{N} \
\det \left ( 1 + h U \right )^{ N_f} \
\left ( 1 + h U^{\dagger} \right )^{ N_f}  \  = \sum_{q=-\infty}^{\infty} Z_q .
\end{eqnarray}

It will be represented as the sum of determinants or sum of usual Schur function
\begin{eqnarray}
Z_q \ = \ h^{-N N_f} \  \ \left ( \prod_{n=1}^{N}  \ \sum_{l_n=0}^{N_f -q} \ h^{2l_n+q}  \ \binom{N_f}{l_n} \right ) \ \underset{1\le i,j\le N}{\det} \binom{N_f}{l_i-i+j+q} =  h^{-N N_f}  \sum_{r=0}^{N N_f}  h^{2 r+ q} \sum_{\lambda \vdash r }s_{\lambda}(1^{N_f})
s_{N^q  \lambda} (1^{N_f})  \ . 
\end{eqnarray}
Expansion in series by small power of $h$ is straightforward:
$$
\frac{Z_q}{ C^{N, N_f} (q)}= 1 + h^2 \frac{N N_f (N_f-q)}{N+q}+ + h^4 \frac{N N_f (N_f-q)}{2!^2 (N+q)} \left(\frac{(N+1) (N_f -1) (N_f-q-1)}{N+q+1}+ \frac{(N -1) (N_f+1) (N_f-q+1)}{N+q-1} \right) + 
$$
$$+ h^6 \frac{N N_f (N_f-q)}{3!^2(N+q)} \left(\frac{(N+1)(N+2) (N_f -1)(N_f-2) (N_f-q-1)(N_f-q-2)}{(N+q+1)(N+q+2)}+ 4 \frac{(N^2-1)(N_f^2-1)((N_f-q)^2-1)}{((N+q)^2-1)} + \frac{(N -2)(N-1) (N_f+2) (N_f+1) (N_f-q+1)(N_f-q+2)}{(N+q+1)(N+q+2)} \right)+ O(h^8)
$$
where
$$
  C^{N, N_f} (q) =\det_{1\le i, j \le N} \ \binom{N_f}{-i +j+q}  =  \frac{G(N+1) G(N+N_f+1) G(q+1) G(N_f+1-q)}{G(N_f+1) G(N+q+1) G(N+N_f+1-q)} \ .
$$
and $G(x)$ is Burness G function.

Similarly, I want to make expansion around $h=1$.

In other topic
[How to calculate determinants of such types?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428319/how-to-calculate-determinants-of-such-types)
I gave the result of expansion by small $\log h= m$ that is finally very elegant:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{Z_q}{ Z_0^{N, N_f} (q)}= 1 + \frac{m^2 R t}{2 \left(4N_f^2-1\right)} +\frac{m^4 R t}{4! \left(4 N_f^2-1\right) }\left(\frac{3 (R+2) (t-2)}{4 N_f^2-9}-2\right)+  \\
&&  + \frac{m^6 R t }{6! \left(4 N_f^2-1\right)} \left(\frac{20 (R+2) (R+6) (t-2) (t-6)}{\left(4 N_f^2-25\right) \left(4N_f^2-9\right)}+ \frac{10 R (R+2) (t-2) t}{\left(4 N_f^2-9\right) \left(4 N_f^2-1\right)} \right. - \nonumber \\
&&\left. -\frac{15 R (R+6) t (t-6)}{\left(4 N_f^2-25\right) \left(4 N_f^2-1\right)}-\frac{5 (R+6) (t-6)}{4 N_f^2-25} -\frac{45 (R+2) (t-2)}{4 N_f^2-9}+\frac{20 R t}{4 N_f^2-1}+16\right) + O (m^8)
\end{eqnarray}
and for the sake of compirison I show expansion in power of $h-1$:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{Z_q}{ Z_0^{N, N_f} (q)}= 1 + (h-1)^2\frac{ R t}{2 \left(4N_f^2-1\right)}- (h-1)^3\frac{ 3 R t}{3! \left(4N_f^2-1\right)} +(h-1)^4\frac{ R t}{4! \left(4 N_f^2-1\right) }\left(\frac{3 (R+2) (t-2)}{4 N_f^2-9}+ 9\right)- (h-1)^5\frac{ R t}{5! \left(4 N_f^2-1\right) }\left(\frac{30 (R+2) (t-2)}{4 N_f^2-9}+ 30\right) \\
&&  + (h-1)^6\frac{ R t }{6! \left(4 N_f^2-1\right)} \left(\frac{20 (R+2) (R+6) (t-2) (t-6)}{\left(4 N_f^2-25\right) \left(4N_f^2-9\right)}+ \frac{10 R (R+2) (t-2) t}{\left(4 N_f^2-9\right) \left(4 N_f^2-1\right)} \right. - \nonumber \\
&&\left. -\frac{15 R (R+6) t (t-6)}{\left(4 N_f^2-25\right) \left(4 N_f^2-1\right)}-\frac{5 (R+6) (t-6)}{4 N_f^2-25} +\frac{210(R+2) (t-2)}{4 N_f^2-9}+\frac{20 R t}{4 N_f^2-1}+ 120\right) + O (m^8)
\end{eqnarray}
where
$$
R = N (N + 2N_f ) , \ \ t= N_f^2- q^2 \ ,
$$
and
$$
  Z_0^{N, N_f} (q) =\det_{1\le i, j \le N} \ \binom{2 N_f}{N_f-i +j+q}  =  \frac{ G[N+ 2 N_f+1] G[N+1] G[N_f-q+1] G[N_f+q+1] }{ G[2 N_f+1] G[N+ N_f- q+1] G[N+ N_f+ q+1] }\  \ ,
$$
About reexpression of first term $Z_0^{N,N_f}$  I asked in [I search representation in terms of Schur Q-function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443813/i-search-representation-in-terms-of-schur-q-function) .
Main contribution at the even powers of $m$ and $h-1$ in both expansion coincides. Sum of the coefficients in the main terms is 0, 1, 3, 15, 105, ... . This    is double factorial of odd numbers (Sequence A001147).
At the denominator we again see a product of numbers like $(2 N_f-3)(2 N_f-1)(2 N_f+1)(2 N_f+3)$  that is the piece of double factorial of odd numbers.

Main bulding block is
$$\frac{ (R+r)  (t-r)}{(4 N_f^2-(4r+1))}$$
where $r$ is promic number ( sequence A002378).
And the structure made from  this block due to some shifted  Young diagram.

Generally it looks like sum over some strict partition.

In the limit of large $N, N_f$ we also have around $h=1$
$$
\log \frac{Z_q}{ Z_0^{N, N_f} (0)}= (\frac{N^2}{2 }+N N_f)  \log \frac{(1+h)(1+1/h)}{4 } + O( (N N_f)^0)
$$
More of this, the sum of cofficients at corresponding  powers of $N (N+2 N_f)$ in above expansion are displayed at the large $N, N_f$
$$
\left[ \frac{(1+h)(1+1/h)}{4} \right]^{(\frac{N^2}{2 }+N N_f)}  = 1+\frac{1}{2 \cdot 4} m^2 N (N+2 N_f)+  m^4\frac{1}{4^2 \cdot 4!} N (N+2 N_f) (3 N (N+2  N_f)-2)+$$
$$+ m^6\frac{ N (N+2 N_f) (15 (N (N+2 N_f))^2 - 30 N (N+2 N_f) +16 )}{4^3 \cdot 6!}$$

Is it possible the expansions around $h=1$ to express in terms of Schur Q-functions or corresponding with it Pfaffians? It would be naturally, because at $h=1$ we deal with strict partitions instead of usual ones. May be we  have a chance to obtain whole expansion in general terms.